# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3) (998,)

Tags: python, numpy

How to deal with this? I have two arrays something like:

```
a = [ 4.39159442  4.3827848   4.37397518  ......................  4.3211174]

b = [[  3.90220220e+02   4.39159442e+00  -4.00073465e-02]
    [  3.90440440e+02   4.38278480e+00  -4.00073465e-02]]
```

I need to divide i.e a/b can someone explain what is going wrong? I use the same data file to import them.

Comment: how do you expect to divide arrays with different dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example:

```
import numpy as np

# I took only 12-elements so it would be easier to see
x1 = np.arange(12.0).reshape((6,2))
x2 = np.arange(6.0).reshape((6,1))

print x1
print x2
print x1 / x2
```

*No errors!*

You must have the same 1st dimension in both arrays for it to work, so what you need to do is `a.reshape((2,998/2))` before the division

like this:

```
x1 = np.arange(998.0).reshape((2,998/2))
x2 = np.arange(6.0).reshape((2,3))
```